# Neo4j cypher query taking time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I have the following schema as depicted in the figure below with lots of `:hub` nodes
and `:node` nodes connected in random order with `:connection` as a common relationship and corresponding `hub id` as an attribute for the relationship.

[image]

I tried the following query and it took a lot of time to execute

```
MATCH (h:hub{id:1})
with h
match (h)-[:connection*{id:1}]->(n:node)
RETURN n
LIMIT 10
```

then I tried the following query for the count

```
MATCH (h:hub{id:1})
WITH h
MATCH (h)-[:connection*{id:1}]->(n:node)
RETURN count(n)
```

Both of them took around 10-20 seconds

I cannot use separate label for each relationship since there are 1000 and more more nodes and neo4j allows only limited labels.

Comment: OP, how large is the graph you are running against?  I ran the queries you indicated against the sample graph provided and it ran in 71ms.  Can you post a sample database somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried PROFILE (just prefix your queries with that) to see the execution plan?

Comment: Try to limit your path length with *..5

Comment: @MichaelHunger I cannot use the *..5 since it will limit the depth.I have to match it with an array to check whether the nodes id's already exsist

Comment: @CharlesChen it will be more than 500, But you check my query I have limited it to 10 and its taking time.

Comment: Even if you limit to 10, we need to know how many needs could potentially be traversed. Is there a way to provide a generator for a sample graph or a sample graph in a zip file?

Comment: @MichaelHunger can I make this query faster without using cypher.